# Is a bivariate normal distribution is only possible (for rv $X$ and $Y$) if $aX+bY \forall a,b \in R$ is normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

[On this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) it is stated that:

> To say that the pair $(X,Y)$ of random variables has a bivariate normal distribution means that every linear combination $aX+bY$ of $X$ and $Y$ for constant (i.e. not random) coefficients $a$ and $b$ has a univariate normal distribution.

Is this to say that if $aX+bY$ does not have an univariate distribution for any $a$ and $b$ then the joint density $f_{XY}$ is not bivariate normal? If so,  is there a way to show this?

Comment: This seems like the contrapositive of the definition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a finte collection of random variables are jointly normal iff any linear combination of them is normal. However degenerate random variables are to be considered normal for this to be true.

Comment: Is there some way to show this?

Comment: This is proved using characteristic functions